# Page Navigate to Itself using jQuery Mobile ajax Navigation Technique +PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an Mobile application based on the jQuery Mobile and Phonegap Framework. I am using jQuery Mobile's Ajax Based Navigation in my application. I mean all the pages in single page template using data-role="page".

However I am stuck with one problem.I am using the jQuery mobile's `$.mobile.changePage('#xyz');` method to navigate between pages.but the problem is when I tap on the button the page go to other page and again comes back on the page from where I had tapped on the button or link. like `a->b->a` again on that page itself. I don't know what is happening. I have no code errors or code issues. I have given `transition="fade"` in my application. I have tried all things including `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` , `"$.mobile.changePage.defaults.allowSamePageTransitions = true;"` but nothing is working.I am not able to copy or paste the code. I have not the permission to do this. but if you guys can provide me the help it will be a great thing.

Hope you all will understand what I want to ask you.

**This is my Edit.**

*For Javascript*

```
$('#secondPage').on('pageinit',function() { jQuery('#itemlist').on('tap',function(){$.mobile.changePage('#homePage',{transition:"fade"});}); });
```

*And For HTML*

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
<a data-role="button" href="#" data-theme="c" data-corners="false" id="itemlist">HomePage</a>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
</div>
</div>
<!- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ->
<div data-role="page" id="homePage">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="c">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: remove your email address from it and paste that code ;)

Comment: Shoe us your HTML code. Also show us your javascript when you initialize changePage. This error usually happens when changePage is called in an incorrect manner or moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with two consecutive events firing one after another:

1. tap event: page changes to #homePage
2. click event: page changes back to #firstPage

Although I don't see an error in your code, this might be a bug o some unexpected behaviour of a browser. Things to consider:

- try removing `href="#"` from the link
- try removing javascript and put `href="#homePage"` in your link.
- try changing the JS event from `tap` to `click` and `return false`.

Comment: However @hegemon ,There is one more issue for arise here. There are two events firing tap and click event on the same element in my code but when page navigate white screen flashes.Do you have solution for this?